Mapbox GL JS - change camera altitude on vertical panning
TL;DR:
How to "fly around" a 3D feature like a building or a mountain at some altitude, then go up a little, and fly around it again? To view the map almost like through an onboard camera of an FPV drone?

How to approach implementing custom panning behaviour in Mapbox GL JS where:

panning horizontally results in map view moving around a sor of a global "horizontal plane"
panning vertically results in map view moving to a new altitude


Here is a demo of a desired panning behaviour using map controls with screenSpacePanning in THREE.js:

Flying around a given level of a building in Mapbox GL JS is tricky (try to do a 360° flight up close to the "MetLife" sign on top of the building):

Both panning actions ideally be uniform, i.e., if on a given map zoom level dragging a mouse horizontally for 100 screen pixels results in moving the map view for 100 meters arond a "horizontal plane", then dragging a mouse for 100px vertically should change map view altitude by the same 100 meters (and without changing the zoom level).
Going underground is acceptable (if that's possible in mapbox), the altitude change might not be bound to the Earth as a planet, but rather occur in a "box of the universe".
